# select from table based on select distinct from another table

Tags: mysql

the case is that I need to select a field distinct from table1 (no duplicates) and use the result as a key to select from another table2.  And I need this to be in one query. Is this possible?!

table1: hID, hName, hLocation 
table2: hID, hFrom, hTo, hRate, hRoomType, hMeals

I want to correct version of this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
JOIN (
    DISTINCT
        hID
    FROM
        table2
    WHERE
        hRoomType = Double Room
ON table1.hID = table2.hID)
```

expected result: all hotels that offer Double Room thanks much –

thanks for help!

Comment: yes but without your table structures cant say anything.

Comment: Thanks Abhik for the immediate reply~

table1: ID(key), hID, Rate, Accom, Room
table2: hID(key), name, location

I need to select hID from table1, using distinct, and the result to select from table2.

Comment: and table2 ? what are the fields ?

Comment: table2: hID(key), name, location I need to select hID from table1, using distinct, and use the result to select from table2.

Comment: Please edit you question, add table, along with tried code.

Comment: Do you want those rows from `table2` with a `hID` that exists in `table1.hID`?

Comment: this is what I have so far:  
"SELECT * FROM table2 JOIN (DISTINCT hID FROM table1 
WHERE hID =value)".....but it's not working

Comment: I've formatted your query for better understanding.

Comment: Also edited my question to match to your question, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague and confusing. Is this what you are looking for:

```
SELECT hID, name, location
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1
ON table1.hID = table2.hID
GROUP BY table2.hID;
```

Comment: table1: hID, hName, hLocation
table2: hID, hFrom, hTo, hRate, hRoomType, hMeals

I want to correct version of this query: SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN (DISTINCT hID FROM table2  WHERE hRoomType = Double Room ON table1.hID = table2.hID)

expected result: all hotels that offer Double Room
thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Here is a skeleton to achieve this:

```
SELECT
    * -- Don't forget to list the requested fields instead of using `*`!
FROM (
    -- This is the distinct list from table1
    SELECT DISTINCT
        id
    FROM
        table1 T1
) DT1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
    ON T1.id = T2.reference_to_t1_id
```

Another solution if you don't want to retrieve any columns from table1:

```
    SELECT
        * -- Don't forget to list the requested fields instead of using `*`!
    FROM
        table2 T2
    WHERE
        -- Sais that get all record from table2 where this condition matches
        -- at least one record
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM table1 T1 WHERE T1.id = T2.reference_to_t1_id
        )
```

**For your tables and question**

```
SELECT
    hID, hName, hLocation
FROM
    table1 T1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM
            table2 T2
        WHERE
            T1.hID = T2.hID
            AND T.hRoomType = 'Double' -- Assuming that this is the definition of double rooms
    )
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Pred!! You solution worked very well. Thanks much man :)